# How can I align?

Tags: vertical-alignment

My code is:

```
\centering {\huge{\textbf{Class name}}}
\vspace{2cm}

\raggedright
Due date: Monday, January 1, 2017, 11:11 PM\\[1.5em]
Textbook: \textbf{Textbook name} \ by \ \textbf{Authors}\\[1.5em]
Solve the following problems: 1, 2, 3, 4.\\[1.5em]
\begin{enumerate}
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 1}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \\[2\baselineskip]
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 2}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \\[2\baselineskip]
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 3}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \\[2\baselineskip]
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 4}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The problem is The index of problem is protruded from the left align above. The picture is the result.

[image]

Comment: `\begin{enumerate}[align=left]`?

Comment: Or probably a better solution would be to use `\begin{enumerate}[wide]` instead.

Comment: @Troy Oh, my god!! That is EXACTLY what I want. Thank you so!! much!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find the solution in the documentation for the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem?lang=en) package. Pass the option `wide` to the `enumerate` environment, like so: `\begin{enumerate}[wide]`.

Here's a MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
{\centering\huge\textbf{Class name}\par}
\vspace{2cm}

\raggedright
Due date: Monday, January 1, 2017, 11:11 PM\\[1.5em]
Textbook: \textbf{Textbook name} \ by \ \textbf{Authors}\\[1.5em]
Solve the following problems: 1, 2, 3, 4.\\[1.5em]
\begin{enumerate}[wide]
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 1}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 2}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 3}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
    \vspace{2\baselineskip}
    \item[\textbf{Exercise 4}] Question!
    \item[\textbf{Solve}] My answer!
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. However, instead of `\centering {\huge{\textbf{Class name}}}`, do write `{\centering\huge\textbf{Class name}\par}`. (Neither `\centering` nor the subsequently employed `\raggedright` take an argument.) Also, instead of `\\[2\baselineskip]`, write something like `\vspace{2\baselineskip}`.

Comment: @Mico Thanks! I copied it from OP's code. Will make the edit!

Comment: I think that a simpler `\begin{center}\huge\bfseries Class name\end{center}` would be better. Probably `\raggedright` was there just for countermanding the effect of `\centering`.